# The time that falls into a time period

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am looking for a way to calculate the time that falls into a datetime period.

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
+------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Name |    Date    |          Start          |           End           |
+------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Me   | 06.02.2018 | 2018-02-06 22:26:00.000 | 2018-02-07 05:21:00.000 |
| Me   | 08.02.2018 | 2018-02-08 19:00:00.000 | 2018-02-08 22:04:00.000 |
+------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I now want to check how much time falls into a certain time window, e.g.:

- 0600 to 2000
- 2000 to 2300
- 2300 to 0600 (next day)
- 0000 to 0400 (next day)

So the result would look like this for the example above:

```
+------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Name |    Date    |          Start          |           End           |  6 - 20  | 20 - 23  |  23 - 6  |  0 - 4   |
+------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Me   | 06.02.2018 | 2018-02-06 22:26:00.000 | 2018-02-07 05:21:00.000 | 00:00:00 | 00:34:00 | 06:21:00 | 04:00:00 |
| Me   | 08.02.2018 | 2018-02-08 19:00:00.000 | 2018-02-08 22:04:00.000 | 01:00    | 02:04    | 00:00:00 | 00:00:00 |
+------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I am struggling with a large line of code:

```
CONVERT(varchar(5),IIF(a.end<(a.date+'00:00'),0,DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, IIF(a.start<(a.date+'00:00'),(a.date+'00:00'),a.start), IIF(a.end>(a.date+0+'04:00'),(a.date+0+'04:00'),a.end)), 0)), 114) [00-04],
```

This is exemplary for what I am trying to achieve but it doesn't work for this time period. The `+0` is there because in some cases I do have `+1` and I am generating the lines of SQL in Excel at the moment.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You've only provided one sample row so will the start and end dates always be on different days or can they be on the same day too?

Comment: It can be on the same day as well. I'll add one example for that as well.

Comment: Have you tried searching SO for `[tsql] time shifts`?

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try, thanks.

Comment: There are a few examples but none that match my specific request to get the exact time in between.

Comment: This answer should help, if anything, as a starting point at least https://stackoverflow.com/a/20907498/3266499

Comment: This seems to be extremely complex and uses different data periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the PIVOT? Check it on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/HLEQ41964).

```
WITH
  t AS (
    SELECT 'Me' "Name",
      CAST(a AS DATETIME) "Date",
      CAST(b AS DATETIME) "Start",
      CAST(c AS DATETIME) "End"
    FROM (
      VALUES ('20180206',
              '20180206 22:26:00.000',
              '20180207 05:21:00.000'),
             ('20180208',
              '20180208 19:00:00.000',
              '20180208 22:04:00.000')
    ) t(a, b, c)
  ),
  d AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      VALUES (6, 20), (20, 23), (23, 30), (24, 28)
    ) t(beg, fin)
  ),
  a AS (
    SELECT t."Date", t."Start", t."End",
      LTRIM(STR(d.beg)) + ' - ' + LTRIM(STR(d.fin)) Range,
      DATEADD(hour, d.beg, t."Date") beg,
      DATEADD(hour, d.fin, t."Date") fin
    FROM t JOIN d
    ON t."Start" <= DATEADD(hour, d.fin, t."Date") AND
       t."End" >= DATEADD(hour, d.beg, t."Date")
  ),
  b AS (
    SELECT "Date", "Start", "End", Range,
      LEFT(
        CONVERT(CHAR(8),
          DATEADD(minute,
            DATEDIFF(minute,
              IIF("Start" > beg, "Start", beg),
              IIF("End" > fin, fin, "End")), 0), 8), 5) Duration
    FROM a
  )
SELECT "Date", "Start", "End",
  COALESCE("6 - 20", '00:00') "6 - 20",
  COALESCE("20 - 23", '00:00') "20 - 23",
  COALESCE("23 - 30", '00:00') "23 - 6",
  COALESCE("24 - 28", '00:00') "0 - 4"
FROM b
PIVOT (
  MIN(Duration)
    FOR Range
      IN ("6 - 20", "20 - 23", "23 - 30", "24 - 28")
) AS p;
```

Comment: Perfect, I really like this. It's easy to maintain and understandable code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more thing, I added another column for the first 4 hours of the day. This could also be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. I got all dates from your table and formed needed time periods. Then looked for overlapping periods and calculated the time. This query will not return rows which `startDate` and `endDate` on same day and before 6 o'clock

```
declare @t table (
    Date date
    , StartDate datetime
    , EndDate datetime
)
insert into @t 
values 
    ('20180206', '20180206 22:26:00.000', '20180207 05:21:00.000')
    , ('20180207', '20180207 05:26:00.000', '20180207 22:21:00.000')
    , ('20180207', '20180207 05:16:00.000', '20180207 05:21:00.000')

;with time_periods as (
    select 
        distinct q.Date, t.n
        , start_date = dateadd(hh, t.b, cast(q.Date as datetime))
        , end_date = dateadd(hh, t.c, cast(q.Date as datetime))
    from 
        @t q
        cross apply (values (1, 6, 20), (2, 20, 23), (3, 23, 30), (4, 24, 28)) t(n, b, c)
)

select
    Date, StartDate, EndDate
    , [6 - 20] = right(concat('0', v1 / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', v1 % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', v1 % 60), 2)
    , [20 - 23] = right(concat('0', v2 / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', v2 % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', v2 % 60), 2)
    , [23 - 6] = right(concat('0', v3 / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', v3 % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', v3 % 60), 2)
    , [0 - 4] = right(concat('0', v4 / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', v4 % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', v4 % 60), 2)
from (
    select
        Date, StartDate, EndDate
        , v1 = max(iif(n = 1, diff, 0))
        , v2 = max(iif(n = 2, diff, 0))
        , v3 = max(iif(n = 3, diff, 0))
        , v4 = max(iif(n = 4, diff, 0))
    from (
        select
            m.Date, m.StartDate, m.EndDate, c.n
            , diff = datediff(ss, iif(m.StartDate < c.start_date, c.start_date, m.StartDate), iif(m.EndDate < c.end_date, m.EndDate, c.end_date))
        from
            @t m
            join time_periods c on m.StartDate <= c.end_date and m.EndDate >= c.start_date and c.Date = m.Date
    ) t
    group by Date, StartDate, EndDate
) t
```

Output

```
Date        StartDate               EndDate                 [6 - 20]    [20 - 23]   [23 - 6]    [0 - 4]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-02-06  2018-02-06 22:26:00.000 2018-02-07 05:21:00.000 00:00:00    00:34:00    06:21:00    04:00:00
2018-02-07  2018-02-07 05:26:00.000 2018-02-07 22:21:00.000 14:00:00    02:21:00    00:00:00    00:00:00
```